# Unity AddExplosionForce() does not apply the explosion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the 'C' key is pressed a new cube is created with a rigid body and added as a child object of 'GameObject'. However, when 'F' is pressed I add explosion to all the child objects but nothing happens. I tried AddForce() and that works fine, it is just AddExplosionForce(). I have just started working with unity so it might be a silly mistake.

Here is my script Update method:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        cube = Instantiate(cubePrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject ParentCube = GameObject.Find("GameObject");
        cube.transform.parent = ParentCube.transform;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        foreach (Transform currentCube in transform)
        {
            Vector3 pointOfExplosion = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.z - 1);
            currentCube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(20, pointOfExplosion, 10, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `GameObject ParentCube = GameObject.Find("GameObject");` (a global search by name) do you perhaps mean `GameObject ParentCube = gameObject`, i.e. parent it to the current one? By the way, to get all Rigidbody child components, you can also just say `GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>()`, which saves you from stepping through all transform childs and grabbing the Rigidbody one by one. In addition, you can calculate the `pointOfExplosion` outside of the loop, as it remains the same. Also, try creating a bigger explosion force, and ensure the rigidbody is not kinematic.

Comment: When you add the cube to the parent, what is the final world position of the child?  The first step would be to go through a debugger and look at the world coordinates of "pointOfExplosion" and "currentCube.transform".  Are the world positions where you expect them to be?

Comment: Isn't that C# code, not UnityScript (a different programming language altogether)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your object to which explosion is added within your 10 units? Also have you tried the overloaded version of AddExplosionForce with the last argument "mode" as an "Impulse"?

From Unity documentation:

> Add an instant force impulse to the rigidbody, using its mass.
> Apply the impulse force instantly with a single function call. This mode depends on the mass of rigidbody so more force must be applied to push or twist higher-mass objects the same amount as lower-mass objects. This mode is useful for applying forces that happen instantly, such as forces from explosions or collisions. In this mode, the unit of the force parameter is applied to the rigidbody as mass*distance/time

Comment: Oh wow thanks, adding the impulse actually works. It blows away the cubes. Not quite sure why it needs it to work though.

Comment: @asciik I've edited my answer so that you could understand better the ForceMode.Impulse